# __getitem__, __setitem__ multiple keys

Tags: python, class, magic-methods, datamodel

I am trying to create a class that stores data in a local buffer as well as acts as an interface to a database. I've got following code:

```
class Table(object):    
    def __init__(self, tableName, **columnDict):
       self.tableName      = tableName
       self.columns        = {}
       self.types          = {}
       self.columns['id']  = []
       self.types['id']    = 'INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL'
       for name in columnDict:
           self.columns[name] = []
           self.types[name]    = columnDict[name]

    def updateBufferRow(self, index, updateDict):
       for key in updateDict:
           self.columns[key][index] = updateDict[key]

    def getBufferRow(self, index):
       row = {}
       for key in self.columns:
           row[key] = self.columns[key][index]
       return row

    def __getitem__(self, key, **args):
       """ Allows using self[key] method """
       return self.getBufferRow(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value, **args):
       """ Allows using self[key] = value method """
       self.updateBufferRow(key, value)
```

Here is how I initialize the table:

```
testTable = Table('BestTable', test = 'TestType', test2='INT')
```

It works as expected the only thing if I try:

```
testTable[0]['test'] = "LALALA"
```

It does nothing, on the other hand this updates rather than overwrites the table:

```
testTable[0] = {"test": "LALALA"}
```

I know I have to rewrite updateBufferRow() and getBufferRow() methods, the only thing I am not quite sure is how to get multiple keys using _*getitem*_ and _*setitem*_ methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dict` returned by your `__getitem__` has no relation any more with your columns. You'll need to return something that perhaps looks like a `dict` but maps `__setattr__` calls back to your table columns:

```
class Row(dict):
    def __init__(self, table, index, *args, **kw):
        self._table, self._index = table, index
        super(Row, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super(Row, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        self._table.columns[key][self._index] = value
```

then return that instead of a regular `dict`:

```
def getBufferRow(self, index):
   row = {}
   for key in self.columns:
       row[key] = self.columns[key][index]
   return Row(self, index, row)
```

Comment: Here is what I did: Moved from {[],[],[]} structure to [{},{},{}]

Comment: @Barmaley: Right, so instead of using mapping of list-per-column you just switched to using a list of row dictionaries. A much better idea if that works for your application. No need to proxy in that case.

Comment: Will it work if there are multiple keys like: `cfg['key_1']['key_2'] = 3`

Comment: @alper: not without additional work. The first key (`cfg['key_1']`) is a `__getitem__` operation, and the `__setitem__` will apply to the result of that operation. So if `cfg` is the custom object you returned, you'll need to control what `__getitem__` returns too.