# Array references in Python class

Tags: python, arrays, class, magic-methods

I created a class that has lots of numpy arrays inside. I created a `__getitem__` function that attempts to return the class with the arrays indexed like so:

`MyClass[i].array1` is equivalent to `MyClass.array1[i]`

I would like the _ _ getitem _ _ to return references, but they are returning copies, so that assignment doesn't work.

```
print(MyClass[i].array1)
```

returns 0

```
MyClass[i].array1 = 10

print(MyClass[i].array1)
```

still returns 0

This is the _get_item_ code I'm using:

```
def __getitem__(self, indices):
    g = copy.copy(self) # should be a shallow copy?
    for key,value in g.__dict__.iteritems():
        g.__dict__[key] = value[indices]
    return g
```

I've also tried:

```
def __getitem__(self, indices):
    g = MyClass()
    for key,value in self.__dict__.iteritems():
        g.__dict__[key] = value[indices]
    return g
```

and:

```
def __getitem__(self, indices):
    g = MyClass()
    g.__dict__ = self.__dict__
    for key,value in g.__dict__.iteritems():
        g.__dict__[key] = value[indices]
    return g
```

Note, this last instance does indeed seem to return references, but not the way I want. If I  index my class using this last code, it performs indexing and truncating on the arrays in the original class, so:

`g = MyClass[i].array1` truncates and overwrites the original array in MyClass to only have elements of index i like so:

```
print(len(MyClass.array1))
```

returns 128

```
print(MyClass[0].array1)
```

returns 0

now `MyClass.array1` is a single float value, obviously not what I wanted.

I hope this is clear enough, and any help would be appreciated.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417962/getitem-setitem-multiple-keys-python) but I wasn't quite sure if this applied to my problem.

Comment: They actually *do* return references - it's just that assigning to a variable rebinds the reference, instead of following the reference and mucking about with the object it refers to. You can write descriptors to get around this, but I'd first question whether it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a really bad idea, but it also seems like a fun problem so here is my crack at it:

```
class MyProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, obj, key):
        super(MyProxy, self).__setattr__('obj', obj)
        super(MyProxy, self).__setattr__('key', key)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.obj, name).__getitem__(self.key)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        return getattr(self.obj, name).__setitem__(self.key, value)

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, array_length):
        self.array_length = array_length

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key >= self.array_length:
            raise IndexError
        return MyProxy(self, key)
```

Example:

```
>>> obj = MyClass(4)  # replace 4 with the length of your arrays
>>> obj.array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> obj.array2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> for c in obj:
...     print c.array1, c.array2
... 
1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
>>> obj[1].array1
2
>>> obj[1].array1 = 5
>>> obj.array1
[1, 5, 3, 4]
```

Comment: That seems to mostly work, though it has trouble with iterating  
  
    for c in MyClass: c.array1 = 0  
  
    ERROR: An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input  
    The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid  
    The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (33, 8))  
  
    --> 180         return getattr(self.obj, name).__setitem__(self.key, value)  
  
    IndexError: index 128 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 128

Comment: Are all your numpy arrays the same length?  If not iteration will be tricky, I guess it could be based on the longest numpy array but this seems kind of weird.

Comment: Yes, they all will have the same length for their first dimension, though some will have an additional 2nd or 3rd dimension. Basically they are time series data and information where the time record is the 1st index.

Comment: It works now with iteration, you just need to pass the length of your arrays when creating the instance.

Comment: That might work, though I would have the length variable set based on the data that is read in during the init rather than passing it explicitly. One issue, though, is that indexing the class doesn't actually return a class object, so none of the methods are attached. Can we get around that by subclassing the original class with the proxy, like: class MyProxy(MyClass) ?

Comment: Yes, subclassing would probably work.  Really though, I would suggest just not doing anything like this and only accessing and modifying your arrays in one consistent way.

Comment: Yes, I've considered that. The issue is that it is convenient to treat the data in two ways, as data records for each 'time point', where you index the class as above, and as 'time records' for the various arrays, which are accessed the 'normal' way. I would like to be able to easily and intuitively plot the arrays vs. time, and I would like to be able to easily slice out data records for time points or ranges of interest, without explicitly slicing each individual array out of the dozens in the Class.